# Osgi Exception in Activator.start()

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I new Start osgi My code is running java application but it is not running osgi the error reason is 'import com.sun.codemodel' how resolve this problem .

My activator class is :

```
package deneme;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import org.jsonschema2pojo.SchemaMapper;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

import com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello World!!");
        String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel();
        try {
            URL sourceRota = new URL("file:///C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/NavsimKisa/rota_yeni.json");
            URL sourceKriter = new URL("file:///C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/NavsimKisa/kriter_yeni.json");
            URL sourceSabit = new URL("file:///C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/NavsimKisa/sabit_yeni.json");

            new SchemaMapper().generate(codeModel, "ClassNameRota", "Rota.entity", sourceRota);
            new SchemaMapper().generate(codeModel, "ClassNameKriter", "Kriter.entity", sourceKriter);
            new SchemaMapper().generate(codeModel, "ClassNameSabit", "Sabit.entity", sourceSabit);

            codeModel.build(new File(workingDir + "/src/main/java"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#stop(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Goodbye World!!");
    }

}
```

my error  :

```
my error is :Hello World!!
!SESSION 2015-10-14 17:46:29.576 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_60
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en
Command-line arguments:  -dev file:D:/navsim3o/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/New_configuration (1)/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -console

!ENTRY deneme 4 0 2015-10-14 17:46:30.794
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in deneme.Activator.start() of bundle deneme.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel cannot be found by deneme_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)

Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/codemodel/JCodeModel
    at deneme.Activator.start(Activator.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel cannot be found by deneme_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to export the package com.sun.codemodel in the system bundle. This is done by the Framework property [org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra](http://spring.io/blog/2009/01/19/exposing-the-boot-classpath-in-osgi/).

Then you need to make sure your own bundle define the import using Import-Package in the Manifest.

Hopefully the library you use does not mess with the classloader then it should work all right.